# Object keeps receiving notification

Tags: objective-c

I have a Book object that listens to a notifications. When I'm trying to remove the book from the view I have this piece of code:

```
BookItem *book = [books objectAtIndex:bookIndex];
    [book removeFromSuperview];
    [books removeObject:book];
    book = nil;
```

After I'm done removing books I send a "rearrange" notification and I'm getting an error in the BookItem object, where I'm accessing nulls ...

What could be the problem? how can I stop listening to notifications after I'm removing the object?

Comment: What kind of notifications? If you called `NSNotificationCenter addObserver` then you must call `NSNotificationCenter removeObserver`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [stop observing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:book];
```